# Checking if component exist - do not render the same component second time

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have one component, it contains two other components. First "NotifyMessage" component is rendered for the whole page. Second "NotifyMessage" component is rendered just only inside pop up. Both components subscribe to the redux store and get appropriate message and type (success or error) from there. Currently, if something happens - "NotifyMessage" component rendered in both places (popup and whole page). What is the best approach to separate render logic? I'd like to render only one component in one place.

Comment: show your one component and tow other components code

Comment: shouldComponentUpdate lifecycle is used for conditional rendering or component

Comment: don't pass `NotifyMessage` state to your children `NotifyMessage`

Answer (score 0):

create a flag State , say "compAlreadyShown" with boolean value. Use it to conditionally show hide in popup.

Comment: I tried things like this. But in my case It doesn't help me

Answer (score 0):

I've added another message to my redux store for "pop'ups" cases and pass it to my common "NotifyMessage" component as a children. For now I've two sources of truth for messages in my store instead of one. May be there is a better solution but it fix my problem.